# Apache and wsgi config for Django

Tags: django, apache2, mariadb, mod-wsgi

I'm struggling to get my Django stuff to appear on my web browser. If I use `python3 manage.py runserver 192.168.0.10:8000`, I can see the Django install and admin page, but I'd like to see it without specifying a port number, and I'm aware that using run server is the development side, rather than deployment. Also worth noting that I have not used any form of VirtualEnv as this is a dedicate Pi/Project, and I was getting confused with the libraries, local python install, virtual python install etc.

I have Django / MySQL / Apache2 up-to-date (as far as I can tell) and there is Django data in the correct db/table.

When navigating to 192.168.0.10/ or 192.168.0.10/admin, I get no error page or default apache page. It sits there for about 5 minutes, then gives me 'can't find page'.

Trying to narrow things down, I think I've got one of three problems:

1. Apache isn't configured correctly
2. Permissions/ownership issue of MySQL (e.g. apache not reading from table)
3. Permissions/ownership issue of dir's (e.g. /var/www)

I posted a similar question not too long ago, I've revisited that and the links that came with it, but it's not helped. I did have PHP and a VirtualEnv installed that time, and this is a fresh installation without either. I'm looking to have php install to have a bit of a gui to manage the MySQL should I need to, so I might do then after posting this and see if it helps.

**Django's settings.py**: I'll provide the important bits:

```
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.0.10', '127.0.0.1']
.....
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
                'init_command': 'SET sql_mode=`STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`',
                'read_default_file': '/etc/mysql/my.cnf',
        },
    }
}
......
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

**MySQL/my.cnf =**

```
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.

#
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
#!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
#!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/

[client]
database = blog_data
host = localhost
user = root
password = xxx
default-character-set = utf8
#SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf** =

```
    ...
 Alias /static /home/pi/test_blog_app/blog/static
        <Directory /home/pi/test_blog_app/blog/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/pi/test_blog_app/blog/blog>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess testblogapp python-path=/home/pi/test_blog_app python-home=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup testblogapp
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/pi/test_blog_app/blog/blog/wsgi.py
```

**Output of sudo nano var/log/apache2/error.log (last few lines) =**

```
Current thread 0xb6fa8e40 (most recent call first):
[Sun Oct 01 16:11:20.397787 2017] [core:notice] [pid 2390:tid 3069873728] AH00052: child pid 2476 exit signal Aborted (6)
[Sun Oct 01 16:11:20.398262 2017] [core:notice] [pid 2390:tid 3069873728] AH00052: child pid 2477 exit signal Aborted (6)
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0xb6fa8e40 (most recent call first):
```

**VERSIONS** 
O/S - Raspbian 9.1 
Apache - 2.4.25 
Django - 1.11.5 
Python - 3.5.3 
MySQL - (Maria) 10.1.23-MariaDB-9+deb9u1 Raspbian 9.0 
PHP - 7.0.19-1

**EDIT** I've attempted to re-install mod_wsgi using
`sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` &
`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`
However, no result

Comment: Define doesn't work. As far as I can see you don't actually say what you see which indicates it is failing. Do you see an error in the browser? Do you get a blank page or does it hang? Do you see the default Apache home page? Are there errors in the Apache error log? It really isn't clear what the real problem is that you need help with.

Comment: How did you install mod_wsgi? From a system provided binary package? Did you compile mod_wsgi from source code yourself? Also, are you using system Python package or did you install that yourself as well?

Comment: To be honest, I can't remember, although I remember making sure to use the one for Python3, which I installed using apt-get (python 3 that is). I have a mod_wsgi.so and mod_wsgi.so-3.5 in /usr/lib/apache2/modules which I found out about from another thread

Comment: Missed it before, don't set ``python-home=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages``. That is wrong. You shouldn't set that if using system Python.

Comment: I removed that from the line, and I spotted a path error in that line that I've correct. Now reads `WSGIDaemonProcess testblogapp python-path=/home/pi/test_blog_app/blog` , restarted apache, ran config test, still no difference. Rebooting to see if that helps

Comment: There is some mismatch between your mod_wsgi and Python installation such that mod_wsgi cannot find the Python installation is was built for. You might uninstall mod_wsgi and reinstall it from system package so ensure is up to date version for your Python installation. Also ensure your Python is up to date from system packages as well.

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a try tomorrow.. `python3 --version` = `Python 3.5.3` 

To uninstall mod_wsgi, is that `sudo purge mod_wsgi' ? Should I remove both of them?

Comment: I don't know what platform you are on and can't guess. You would use your package manager tools to remove/re-install. So ``apt-get``, ``rpm``, ``yum``, or ``dnf`` depending on platform.

Comment: Sorry, I'm running Debian 9, latest Pi OS. I tried to remove `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove libapache2-mod-wsgi` but it came back saying it wasn't installed, yet I have two modules in the apache2 modules folder. I also didn't realise it was your module. I'm going to follow https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html and see how I get on

Comment: If going to reinstall mod_wsgi, look at the ``pip install`` method. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

Comment: Checked out and attempted to follow link, tried to run `mod_wsgi-express start-server` but got a command not found error, and the same with module-config. I'm at a complete loss, and I think I'm going to have to re-visit this issue at a later stage, probably starting with the server install from scratch, might even move away from the RaspberryPi